# Dynamic Forms with ng-repeat

Tags: html, angularjs, forms

Good day!I am using dynamic forms in displaying my data. I want to display two forms on page load if the specific model has two values. My problem is that if even my model has two values, the displayed form is only one and if I click add button, the additional form contains the second value of my model.

```
<div class="text-left">
    <h3>Title<button class="btn btn-primary pull-right" type="button" ng-click="remove(Item)" value=""><span class="fa fa-minus"></span></button>&nbsp;<button class="btn btn-primary pull-right" type="button" ng-click="add()" value=""/><span class="fa fa-plus"></span></button></h3>
</div>
<br/><legend></legend>
<div id="web" ng-repeat="Item in FormData.link">
    <div class="row col-xs-12">
        <div class="col-xs-6">
            <br/><br/>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-md-6 control-label">*Category: </label>
                <select class="pull-left" id="Category" name="Category" ng-model="LinkNew[$index].category" required/>
                    <option value="0">Web</option>
                    <option value="1">Local</option>
                    <option value="2">International De</option>

                </select>
            </div>
            <br/><br/><br/>
```

and my controller looks like this

```
$scope.FormData = {};
            $scope.FormData.link = [
                    {  category: null }
            ];
            $scope.add = function() {
                    $scope.FormData.link.push({  category: null });
            };

            $scope.remove = function(Item) {
                //console.log(subscriber);
                $scope.FormData.link.pop(Item);
            };
```

Answer (score 0):

The `ng-repeat` directive needs items in the collection to be different.
Add something to make them different:

```
var linkId = 0;

$scope.FormData = {};

$scope.FormData.link = [
    { id: linkId++, 
      category: null }
];

$scope.add = function() {
    $scope.FormData.link.push({ id: linkId++,
                                category: null });
};

$scope.remove = function(Item) {
    //console.log(subscriber);
    $scope.FormData.link.pop(Item);
};
```

Each time a new item is added, the `linkId` variable is incremented.

To make the `ng-repeat` directive more efficient, track by the unique ID:

```
<div id="web" ng-repeat="Item in FormData.link track by Item.id">
```

To minimize creation of DOM elements, `ngRepeat` uses a function to "keep track" of all items in the collection and their corresponding DOM elements. For example, if an item is added to the collection, `ngRepeat` will know that all other items already have DOM elements, and will not re-render them.

The default tracking function **does not allow duplicate items** in arrays. This is because when there are duplicates, it is not possible to maintain a one-to-one mapping between collection items and DOM elements.

For more information, see [AngularJS ng-repeat Directive API Reference - Tracking and Duplicates](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat#tracking-and-duplicates)

Comment: Can you provide me with a working snippet? it would be a great help. Thank you very much